# Converting from DatagramPacket to int

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

Is there a way to convert a `DatagramPacket` to an `int` after I have received it?

I'm receiving it like this

```
DatagramSocket aSocket = null;

    try 
    {
        aSocket = new DatagramSocket(6789);

        byte [] buffer = new byte [1000];

        while (true)
        {
            DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            aSocket.receive(request);
        }
```

Comment: it is cool question, but have you researched about it?http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26405&seqNum=4

Comment: do you mean can you convert the contents of `byte[1000]` to an `int`?

Comment: I want to send an int over a DatagramSocket. I can't figure out how to send an int, so I'm sending a string. That's why I want to convert it to an int once i receive it.

Comment: If you are sending the value as a `string`, then take the received bytes, convert them into a `string`, and use `Integer.parseInt()`.  To send an `int` without sending as a `string`, look at the `ByteBuffer` class.